# What does Dax's idiom about feet mean?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, language-explanation

In the Deep Space Nine episode *Dramatis Personae* there is a scene with Kira and Dax where the follow exchange takes place:

> KIRA: How are you, Lieutenant?
>    DAX: You know what they say, put the shoe on the right foot first, but put the left foot first into the bathtub.
>    KIRA: I understand. But what I really meant was, are you happy?

What is the meaning of Dax's line? I've never heard the saying before it was on the show and on the surface it doesn't appear to have any alternative meaning.

Comment: I thought this question was going to be about Crewman Dax in ST: The Undiscovered Country. Because as every Russian know, if shoe fits, wear it. [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BskPW.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BskPW.jpg)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Dax seems to have a remarkable grasp of ancient fables and superstitions, and she's obviously familiar with [Iamblichus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamblichus)' *Life of Pythagoras*.

She's referring to two old superstitions which were first put together by the Ancient Greek philosopher [Pythagoras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras).  The first half of the line refers to the belief that it is unlucky to put your left shoe on before the right.  The second half of the line refers to an ancient belief that the left side is somehow less virtuous than the right side.  Bathing was seen as a somewhat base, mundane, and unclean activity, and so it was preferable to step into the bath with your left foot rather than the right foot.

> It was at one time thought unlucky to put on the left shoe before the right, or to put either shoe on the wrong foot. It is said that Augustus Cæsar was nearly assassinated by a mutiny one day when he put on his left shoe first.
>
> Put on the right shoe first. **One of the auditions of Pythagoras was this: “When stretching forth your feet to have your sandals put on, first extend your right foot, but when about to step into a bath, let your left foot enter first.” Iamblichus says the hidden meaning is that worthy actions should be done heartily, but base ones should be avoided**. (Protreptics, symbol xii.).
> [E. Cobham Brewer, Dictionary of Phrase and Fable (1898)](http://www.bartleby.com/81/15276.html)

The actual quote from Pythagoras, and the explanation by Iamblichus:

> SYMBOL 12.
>
> When stretching forth your feet to have your sandals put on, first extend your right foot; but when about to use a foot-bath, first extend your left foot.
>
> Explanation.--This Symbol exhorts to practical prudence, admonishing us to place worthy actions about us as right-handed; but entirely to lay aside and throw away such as are base, as being left-handed.
> [Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/gvp/gvp11.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I was mostly expecting that it would have just been made up for the show.

Comment: @Xantec - Thank you for asking the question.  I didn't know any of this, I just stumbled across it.  I love it when I get to learn in the process of answering questions.

Comment: * sigh * — Even Pythagoras doesn't like us southpaws… :-(

Comment: Is this Jadzia Dax? Because she's female.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I have no idea.  I don't watch Star Trek.

Comment: @OrganicMarble [Season 1](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Dramatis_Personae_(episode)), so yes, Jadzia would've been the current host.  (That said, Ezri is also female.  The only male hosts during the show's run were each in a single episode, one of which didn't even happen due to an erased timeline)

Comment: Does this really answer the question? It provides a supposed interpretation of Dax's literal response, but substituting in that interpretation into the conversation still doesn't make sense: "How are you?" followed by "Do good things with your right hand and bad things with your left." sounds ridiculous to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner In the context of the episode it sort of makes sense. Dax was constantly retelling old stories that had little to do with the conversation at hand.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes it does. Dax isn't exactly herself at the time, and keeps going off on odd tangents that don't make much sense in context, so finding out what the reference is to is all we can expect. Explaining it in the context of the conversation is already off the table.

Comment: I haven't seen the episode, but is it possible she means "I'm trying to follow protocol and keep my priorities straight, even though none of it makes much sense to me these days"?

Comment: Wait a second... *literally cleaning yourself* was seen as an unclean activity?!?  Just when you thought the ancient Greeks couldn't get any more screwed up, they always find some new way to surprise you...

Comment: @Beta If you can find a quote of a production member saying that then that would make a good answer. But as the character is out of sorts at the time, interpreting her *intended* meaning is about impossible.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - I think it is better to say that bathing was a "base" activity, one that is necessary but not morally valuable.  It's just something you *have* to do.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I assumed that "Dax" was the character's first name, and the only other "Dax" I know of is a guy in *Star Wars*, so I assumed that the character was a man.

Comment: Even if you would watch Star Trek occasionally, Dax is always called "old man" by Sisko, so you could easily conclude that she's from a species where the males look like female humans.

Comment: @MrLister - I also assumed that she was actually human.

Comment: @DanielWagner - The question asked what the idiom means, not why the character mentioned the idiom.  There is no room to argue that she wasn't referring to Pythagoras (and Iamblichus), since that's the origin of the phrase.  If you can explain why she made reference to an Ancient Greek parable, feel free to add your own answer.  I think I fully addressed the issue of what the idiom means, which is the only thing that was actually asked in the question.  If you can do better, you'll have my upvote.

Comment: @Daniel_Wagner As an answer to "How are you?" it could make sense as a long-winded, cryptic, pedantic way of saying, "It all depends upon context."